# Determine how a type was defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019. A large, complex 3rd party library we use defines a number of types, some of them buried deep in library headers. Say one of the types is:

```
typedef unsigned char FancyType
```

An example use in my client code (say `MySource.cpp`) might be:

```
FancyType testConnection = SomeLibraryMethod();
```

When you hold the mouse over `FancyType`, VS2019 correctly displays `typedef unsigned char FancyType` in a popup window, but no information about where this type was defined. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click `FancyType` to open the relevant header file and the type definition is helpfully highlighted for you. Lets say the header is `BuriedLibraryFile.h`.

There is no `#include "BuriedLibraryFile.h"` anywhere in my own source code.

Theoretically, the `typedef` could have been defined directly in `MySource.cpp`. Or in `MySource.h`. Or in a header included in `MySource.cpp` or `MySource.h`. Or in a header included in a header included in...(and so on recursively). But Visual Studio doesn't show any of the intermediate recursive header chain, only the final file.

What techniques can analyse **where** the relevant `#include` came from? A possible use case might be "If I add a new class to the project, what is the minimal #include required to ensure FancyType is defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options I can think of:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (Find All References...) to see where the given type is used, that usually provides an idea of which header is pulling it in (though is only 1-level deep).
2. Compile the file with the `/showIncludes` flag. That dumps the #include tree during compilation, from which you can see how a given file is included.

   [image: VS 2019 showIncludes flag]

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The `/showIncludes` flag works well. Simply (temporarily) turn it on, compile, dump the output to a text editor and analyse. Remember to turn `/showIncludes` off.